# PropertyGrid selection bug when properties have identical DisplayName?

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a `PropertyGrid` whose selected object contains multiple properties with `[DisplayName]`s of "Speed", all in different categories (the real property names in the code are of course all unique). I've noticed that if I have (for example) Speed #3 selected and `PropertyGrid.Refresh()` is called, the selection will automatically move to Speed #1. What's more, the value of Speed #3 will sometimes be shown next to Speed #1 too. The situation resolves itself as soon as I click the grid and change the selection, but it's obviously not desired behavior.

I am currently hacking around this by adding different numbers of `\t` characters to the `DisplayName`s to make them all unique. This is an acceptable workaround since the tab characters aren't actually rendered, but I'd of course prefer not to have to do it.

Is there a rule that all `DisplayName`s must be unique or is this a bug in `PropertyGrid`?

---

Update: Since someone's bound to ask for a code sample, stick one of these in a `PropertyGrid` and then call `Refresh()` on it from a timer every two seconds or so:

```
class Demo
{
    [Category("Cat1")]
    [DisplayName("Speed")]
    public int Speed1 { get; set; }

    [Category("Cat2")]
    [DisplayName("Speed")]
    public int Speed2 { get; set; }

    [Category("Cat3")]
    [DisplayName("Speed")]
    public int Speed3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a bug, it's probably a feature (with side effects :-). You can check the property grid source on Microsoft site. The relevant portion seems this in [GridEntry.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/ndp/fx/src/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PropertyGridInternal/GridEntry.cs#2f724cfd0790fe6a) code:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) {
  if (NonParentEquals(obj)) {
    return((GridEntry)obj).ParentGridEntry == this.ParentGridEntry;
  }
  return false;
}

internal virtual bool NonParentEquals(object obj) {
  if (obj == this) return true;
  if (obj == null) return false;
  if (!(obj is GridEntry)) return false;
  GridEntry pe = (GridEntry)obj;

  return pe.PropertyLabel.Equals(this.PropertyLabel) &&
    pe.PropertyType.Equals(this.PropertyType) && pe.PropertyDepth == this.PropertyDepth;
}
```

As you see, it's the PropertyLabel which is used. If you follow the code a bit more, the label will ultimately use the property's DisplayName (or the name if the DisplayName attribute is not defined).

Comment: That certainly does seem to explain why it happens. But... `GridEntry` has an overridable `PropertyDescriptor` attribute. It seems like that could be leveraged here if it returns nonnull, or that `PropertyDescriptorGridEntry` could override `NonParentEquals` to add that check, but who knows. Whatever the case, it does seem to show that there is an unwritten (as far as I know) rule that each property you expose in the grid needs to have a unique combination of display name, type, and tree depth.

Comment: The GridEntry we see are in fact PropertyDescriptorGridEntry which are bound to a specific PropertyDescriptor, plus all this is internal, so, there's not way to change this unless with big big hacks...

Comment: Right; I was just wondering why the original developers didn't do one of those things in the first place. But it's obviously moot now; at least I have a workaround!